# Good python library for designing a mmo? Actor based design

Tags: python, stackless, python-stackless, mmo

i m trying to design a mmo game using python...

I have evaluated stackless and since it is not the general python and it is a fork, i dont want to use it

I am trying to chose between
pysage
candygram
dramatis
and
parley

any one try any of these libraries?

Thanks a lot for your responses

Comment: before start you should watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eslYlbe3gw :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go for [pysage](http://code.google.com/p/pysage/).

It has the highest level of abstraction and a lightweight messaging API which will give you lots of flexibility.   I would imagine when designing an MMO you will want as much flexibility as possible.

It also takes a page from Erlang's Actor model which is really solid.

That's great you are trying to build an MMO via python!  It has great OpenGL bindings when you want to add graphics which is great!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Initially [Twisted Python](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) was designed to write MMOs, but it not really easy to use. I don't know if there is an Actor implementation for it, perhaps in the [tx project in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/tx) ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write an MMO in Python, it was horrible. Now I have switched to Erlang and its lightyears ahead of other languages in terms of developing server software. You can check my project at: http://www.next-gen.cc.

Btw writing the client graphics in OpenGL is a huge task, you probably want something like Ogre3d (there are python bindings).